# HTML page with embedded JWPlayers not working any more

Tags: html, css, jwplayer

**EDIT: PROBLEM SOLVED. It was the FitVids code causing the JWP to not display. Thanks to all for your help.**

I've been staring at my code too long and can't figure out why it's not working after I made a couple of small mods. Can one of you clever folk check it and let me know what I've done wrong?

The page is supposed to have three embedded JWPlayer in it with some random video. The CSS file it is using should be the one for desktop screens, but I also have one there for iphone.

http://www.billarga.com/newsite/

The code below shows the integration of one of the three players.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
      http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <title>New Site</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.billarga.com/newsite/player/jwplayer.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (max-device-width: 480px)" href="http://www.billarga.com/newsite/css/iphone.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:portrait)" href="http://www.billarga.com/newsite/css/ipad-portrait.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:landscape)" href="http://www.billarga.com/newsite/css/ipad-landscape.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (min-device-width: 1025px)" href="http://www.billarga.com/newsite/css/ipad-landscape.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (min-width: 1824px)" href="http://www.billarga.com/newsite/css/screen.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://www.billarga.com/newsite/js/jquery.fitvids.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#page-wrapper").fitVids();
      });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="page-wrapper">
        <div id="video-wrapper">
            <div id="video">Video 1</div>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    jwplayer('video').setup({
                    'flashplayer': 'http://www.billarga.com/newsite/player/player.swf',
                    'file': 'http://www.billarga.com/newsite/content/0000001/1.mp4',
                    'controlbar': 'bottom',
                    'width': '480',
                    'height': '360'
                    });
                </script>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
  body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: medium;
    }
    a           { color: blue; text-decoration: none; }
    a:visited       { color: blue; text-decoration: none; }
    a:hover             { color: blue; text-decoration: underline; }
    h1          { font-size: x-large; text-align: center; }
    #page-wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    }
    #video-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 360px;
    }
    #video {
    float: left;
    }
```

Comment: Please post some of the relevant HTML and JS code in here. Otherwise, the question will lose all value to future readers once the problem is solved. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for fixing up the CSS code above Pekka.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try putting your jwplayer inside jQuery's document ready callback, like so:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#page-wrapper").fitVids();

    jwplayer('video').setup({
        'flashplayer': 'http://www.billarga.com/newsite/player/player.swf',
        'file': 'http://www.billarga.com/newsite/content/0000001/1.mp4',
        'controlbar': 'bottom',
        'width': '480',
        'height': '360'
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: I would do that, but there will be 3 players in that page so I'd prefer to keep the callback in the headers and the player in the body. I hope that makes sense. Thanks anyway.

Comment: You can do that; however, it's still wise to wrap it in a document ready callback. Just make a new one, you can have as many on the page as you like, in the head or the body. (While you should still do this, I don't think it will fix your problem; I can't get it to work when running the operation by hand. I'd check the validity of your SWF, and go through the documentation here: http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/12540/javascript-api-reference )

Comment: The strange thing is that it was all working just a few hours ago, then I fiddled with the code and the springs went flying. I'll check the swf. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Did you copy and paste the second and third players from the first one? If so, it might just stick one player on the page until you change the names e.g. video_1, video_2, video_3.